# Эмулятор в Android Studio на Windows 10 выдает ошибку 1

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор

При запуске программы выдается ошибка

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: вопрос-то какой?

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в Tools -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools и убедитесь, что у вас установлен эмулятор, как на скриншоте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После установки перезапустите Android Studio.
Эмулятор не работает на процессорах AMD. Если у вас AMD, используйте сторонний эмулятор, например Genymotion.

Comment: Стоит галочка, установлено. У меня intel i5 nvidia geforce gtx. Не работает

Comment: Визуализация должна быть включена в BIOS, проверьте

Comment: как это сделать? дайте ссылку на гайд. я новенький

Comment: Здесь универсального рецепта нет, какая модель материнской платы? ВОт здесь можете глянуть пример как это делается http://fb.ru/article/236283/kak-v-biose-vklyuchit-virtualizatsiyu-prosteyshim-sposobom